# Can IntelliJ format SQL code with keywords right-aligned and other content left-aligned?

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, code-formatting

Is it possible to create this kind of formatting in IntelliJ for SQL code?

```sql
SELECT p.PersonId,
       p.FirstName,
       p.LastName,
       c.Name
  FROM Person AS p 
  JOIN City AS c 
    ON p.CityId = c.CityId;
```

[This article](https://dzone.com/articles/24-rules-to-the-sql-formatting-standard) discusses the advantages of this style. I would like to try it in IntelliJ 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as far as one can get with formatting your query by tweaking IntelliJ's `Code Style > SQL > Queries` settings.

[image: Select query formatting example]

To achieve this, set `Align the first word of clause` property to `To left with indent`. However, as you can notice, `ON` keyword is not aligned according to the requested style. Unfortunately, this is a known limit of IntelliJ as there is no there is no `JOIN indented` option present in SQL formatter under `SELECT > FROM > Place ON/USING under` property (see [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-8061)).

[image: JOIN indented missing]

I haven't tested it on more complex queries, but I believe more problems will arise. So, I am afraid, as of July 2019, the answer to your question is negative and such formatting should be done manually (at least within IntelliJ, DataGrip and similar tools created by JetBrains).

Comment: Could you please export and pass your XML config for SQL formatting?

Answer (score 3):

Set the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | SQL | MySQL | Queries | Common | *Align the first word of clause* option 'To right':
[image]